# How many index we can create in indexed db?

Tags: indexeddb

I am using indexeddb.

I have many filters in my project, to achieve result I have added many indexes.

How many indexes we can create? Is there any limit on creating indexes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the ideal.
Unlimited number you can have if you got enough disk space.

The more indexes, themore overhead on insertion process because of you have to add data to each indexes and re-index.
A good side is you can gain a good speed to access your data that you indexed.